# Gridview not listening to HeaderStyle.Width = 183

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Can anyone explain this one to me. I'm trying to set the sizes of a GridView.

`int totalWidth = 550;

int subWidth = totalWidth / _module.Values.Count;`

with 3 modules this comes to 183, and with 2 it's 275.

Later in the code I do a:
`myGrid.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;

        myGrid.HeaderStyle.Width = subWidth;`

Now I would have assumed the width of the columns would be 183px with 3 modules, or 275 with 2. Actual sizes are: 224 + 153 + 172 = 549. The headertext of column 1 is long, but if I force it to be 183px, why does it insist of being 224? Text is column 2 is short, column 3 medio long. There is still plenty of space for all 3 headers to be squeezed a bit.

Just to be clear - I'm also doing a:
`myGrid.RowStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;

myGrid.RowStyle.Width = subWidth;`

I see the same wrong sizes in both Firefox and Chrome. I cannot get it into my stupid head how I can set a width and the column decides on another value despite my intentions.

Method in question:

> > private void CreateGridView()
> >         {
> >             GridView myGrid = new GridView();
> >             int totalWidth = 550;
> >             int subWidth = totalWidth / _module.Values.Count;
> >
> > ```
> >     #region DataTable
> >
> >     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
> >
> >     string[] dataArray = new string[_module.Values.Count];
> >
> >     for (int i = 0; i < _module.Values.Count; i++)
> >     {
> >         dataArray[i] = _module.Values[i].Value.ToString("n0"); ;
> >     }
> >
> >     for (int i = 0; i < _module.Values.Count; i++)
> >     {
> >         dataTable.Columns.Add(_module.Values[i].Text.ToString());
> >     }
> >
> >     dataTable.Rows.Add(dataArray);
> >
> >     myGrid.DataSource = dataTable;
> >
> >     #endregion
> >
> >     myGrid.Width = totalWidth;
> >
> >     myGrid.GridLines = GridLines.None;
> >
> >     myGrid.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
> >     myGrid.HeaderStyle.Width = subWidth;
> >
> >     myGrid.RowStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
> >     myGrid.RowStyle.Width = subWidth;
> >
> >     myGrid.DataBind();
> >
> >     Controls.Add(myGrid);
> > }
> > ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set CssClass on the GridView (as well as other children of the GridView such as HeaderStyle, RowStyle and so on) and set the width on that, rather than having your UI/design elements inside of compiled code?

I would create a stylesheet, or add to an existing stylesheet with a class declaration:

```
.myStyle {
    width: 550px;
}

.myStyle2Modules {
     width: 750px;
}

.myStyleLotsOfModules {
     width: 1000px;
}
```

and then reference the class. You can then tweak the UI positions and widths on the fly by editing the CSS. You can programatically choose the CSS class in the code, but the actual definitions of those styles are in the stylesheet.

Let your code handle the functionality, nuts and bolts and implementation - let the stylesheet handle all the design elements such as colours, fonts, widths, borders and so on

Comment: Thanks for the CSS reminder, though it didn't change anything.

Comment: If it has not worked then you have some hardcoded widths or styles in there still that are either invalid or conflicting - take a look at http://atashbahar.com/post/GridView-makeover-using-CSS.aspx which has a sample setup of a GridView in conjunction with a stylesheet for all UI elements - remember that when you design a GridView in the designer, dragging handles and making changes using the UI rather than the code will often end up with hardcoded styling applied in your view (aspx, ascx and so on)

Comment: I don't ever drag and drop anything out of the designer tools. That be the big evil, making all sorts of code you have no control over. Funny is - we changed the length of the text and it adjusted the width size accordingly. That only confused me even more.